# A function of $u(0,1)$ random variables converging weakly to an exponential

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

This is a review problem for my final exam: Let $(X_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with $X_{i} \sim U(0,1)$. Let $M_{n}=\max_{1\leq i \leq n}X_{i}$. Show that $n(1-M_{n})$ converges weakly to an exponential distribution with parameter $1$.

I attempted to solve this problem using characteristic functions and Levy's Continuity Theorem. Perhaps the issue is what the characteristic function of $n(1-M_{n})$ is supposed to look like, because I was unable to get the expectation of that characteristic function to converge to $\frac{1}{1-iu}$, the characteristic function of an exponential with parameter $1$.

Anyway, this is what I did:

\begin{align}
\varphi_{n(1-M_{n})}&=E\{exp(iun(1-M_{n}))\}=\exp(iun)E\{\exp(-iunM_{n})\}\\
&=\exp(iun)\cdot\frac{1}{1-0}\int_{0}^{1}\exp(-iunM_{n})dM\\
& =-\frac{1}{iun}[\exp(-iunM_{n})]_{0}^{1}\\
&=-\frac{1}{iun}[\exp(-iun)-1]=\frac{\exp(iun)+1}{iun},
\end{align} which does not go to $\frac{1}{1-iu}$ as $n \to \infty$.

What do I need to do differently in order to make it work? I want to be able to handle problems like this on the final, so please help!! If characteristic functions aren't necessarily the best way to approach this problem, please tell me a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably better to use the cumulative distribution function, since it behaves better with respect to the maximum of an independent sequence. We have
$$\mu\{n(1-M_n)\leqslant t\}=\mu\{1-t/n\leqslant M_n\}=1-(1-t/n)^n$$
and we recognize a well-known limit.

Comment: Can you please explain in greater detail where the last part comes from: the $1-(1-t/n)^{n}$ part? I know that the $(1-t/n)^{n}$ comes from i.i.d., but what about the additional $1- $ out front?

Comment: "$M_n$ is greater than $a$ " is the complement of "each $X_i$ is smaller than $a$".

Comment: The complement of, or equal to? Because in order to get $1-(1-\frac{t}{n})^{n}$, we need to have $P(1-\frac{t}{n} > X_{1})^{n}$ in the previous step, which would mean that we would need $P(1-\frac{t}{n} \leq M_{n})=P(1-\frac{t}{n}>X_{i})$. I'm sorry about all the follow ups, but I just really want to understand this, and I have nobody else to ask.

Comment: Maybe just writing out, not skipping any steps or justifications would help.